# Installation of transformer library not working in Apple M1

Tags: python, rust, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, libtorch

I'm attempting to install [rust-bert](https://github.com/guillaume-be/rust-bert). Unfortunately, I have an Apple M1 and the library isn't designed for the new ARM chip. Specifically, the pytorch and libtorch libraries aren't linked.

The error is described in this [github issue](https://github.com/guillaume-be/rust-bert/issues/326). I've followed the advice in the thread and neither proposed solution works. It wold be super useful to the Rust community if we could have a solution that works as this looks like an exciting library with a large number of applications.

EDIT - A full description of the problem - I can't make install the library because the library says that libtorch is not available for mac arm64. I've installed the library via homebrew, via during downling and installing pytorch and through anaconda. I've also changed the symlinking. Nothing so far has worked.

Here is the error snippet including the libraries that are built incorrectly -

```
  = note: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/peterweyand/Code/rust-bert/target/debug/build/torch-sys-d926b35b7e909d7c/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib/libtorch.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
          ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/peterweyand/Code/rust-bert/target/debug/build/torch-sys-d926b35b7e909d7c/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
          ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/peterweyand/Code/rust-bert/target/debug/build/torch-sys-d926b35b7e909d7c/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib/libc10.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
          Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
```

I've added issues on github -

https://github.com/guillaume-be/rust-bert/issues/326

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/96959

I've tried the last three versions of pytorch (1.13.0, 1.13.1, and 2.0.0) using `pip3 install torch===1.13.0` with the same errors.

So it doesn't look like it's a versioning issue.

Here's my python environment according to the pytorch error requirements -

```
Versions

peterweyand@Peters-MacBook-Pro rust-bert % python collect_env.py
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 2.0.0
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: None
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: macOS 13.1 (arm64)
GCC version: Could not collect
Clang version: 15.0.7
CMake version: version 3.25.1
Libc version: N/A

Python version: 3.8.16 (default, Mar 1 2023, 21:18:45) [Clang 14.0.6 ] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: macOS-13.1-arm64-arm-64bit
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: No CUDA
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: N/A
GPU models and configuration: No CUDA
Nvidia driver version: No CUDA
cuDNN version: No CUDA
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

CPU:
Apple M1 Pro

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.24.2
[pip3] torch==2.0.0
[pip3] torchaudio==2.0.1
[pip3] torchvision==0.15.1
[conda] numpy 1.24.2 pypi_0 pypi
[conda] numpy-base 1.23.5 py38h90707a3_0
[conda] torch 2.0.0 pypi_0 pypi
[conda] torchaudio 2.0.1 pypi_0 pypi
[conda] torchvision 0.15.1 pypi_0 pypi
```

Comment: Please provide a full description of the issue within the post, while links to external resources often give valuable support information, the questions asked on Stack Overflow *have to be* self sufficient. Without looking at the link one cannot properly answer your question, therefore it is currently lacking details.

Comment: Install pytorch 1.13, seems to be available in homebrew for ARM architecture.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/96959 I have pytorch 2.0.0. Does Pytorch 2 not use ARM? I've attempted to uninstall and reinstall pytorch and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of Intel-only and ARM-only libraries on your computer.

I'm not sure which ones come from where, but either your Homebrew or your Rust has been installed before you switched to the M1 Mac, and is still in an Intel version, and runs emulated under Rostetta without knowing you have ARM Mac.

You need to purge all Intel-only libraries from your system.

Reinstall Rust: `rustup self uninstall` and then https://rustup.rs again. Fresh install will give you a new Apple Sillicon-compatible version of Rust.

If that doesn't help, then your Homebrew is Intel-only, and update or reinstall Homebrew.

---

[torch-sys](//lib.rs/torch-sys) downloads libtorch from https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-macos-1.13.0.zip and this zip file includes library for Intel only.

You may need to ask https://pytorch.org/ to start building the library as a Universal Binary that supports ARM.

https://github.com/LaurentMazare/tch-rs/issues/629

Comment: So I've uninstalled Rust, Brew, and Python and reinstall each to the latest version. I removed pytorch versions from the python directory and installed the latest pytorch in brew (which is version 1.13.1). I still have the error. Is there a folder or simlinks I should delete somewhere? `warning: ignoring file /Users/peterweyand/Code/rust-bert/target/debug/build/torch-sys-d926b35b7e909d7c/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64` Still warning - I deleted and remade target folder.

Comment: Does `rustup show` print `Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin`?

Comment: `peterweyand@Peters-MacBook-Pro opt % rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/peterweyand/.rustup

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.68.0 (2c8cc3432 2023-03-06)` See my comment here - https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/96959#issuecomment-1472581856. That's as clean of a fresh install of python as I can make.